# how can I get current guild ID in on_member_join

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making bot that will be on 3~4 servers,

and I was working on welcome messages.

I saw this post : [Discord.py welcome message for multiple servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62667213/discord-py-welcome-message-for-multiple-servers)
and doing that way but there were some errors,
I'm doing my way.

but eventually i stuck to a problem that I can't get guild id in on_member_joined.

using discord.py 1.4.2

please help me.

any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: How do you expect us to help fix something we can't see or access? If you want help then we will need the code so we can actually find the error and fix it. So please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Member` object has a `guild` attribute use that to get the `id.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(member.guild.id)
    print(member.guild.name)
```

Docs:

- [`Member.guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Member.guild)
- [`on_member_join`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.on_member_join)