# welcome message code for multiple servers

Tags: discord.py

I recently started to learn discord.py and I wanted to add a welcome message for multi-channels and I found this post [Discord.py welcome message for multiple servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62667213/discord-py-welcome-message-for-multiple-servers/62723131#62723131) I tried the code and seems to be working without any errors but I'm facing a problem creating a welcome message with this code because I don't have experience with discord.py I will have the code listed below and at the very bottom I will have the welcome code I tried if somebody can help it would be great
Thank you

````
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    #loads json file to dictionary
    with open("welcome-message.json", "r") as f:
        guildInfo = json.load(f)

    guildInfo[guild.id] = guild.text_channels[0] #sets key to guilds id and value to top textchannel
    
    #writes dictionary to json file
    with open("welcome-message.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(guildInfo, f)

#allows server members to set channel for welcome messages to send to    
@client.command()
async def welcomeMessage(ctx):
    with open("welcome-message.json", "r") as f:
        guildInfo = json.load(f)

    guildInfo[ctx.message.guild.id] = ctx.message.channel.id #sets channel to send message to as the channel the command was sent to

    with open("welcome-message.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(guildInfo, f)


# welcome code
@client.event
async def on_member_join(ctx, message):
    with open("welcome-message.json", "r")as f:
        guildInfo = json.load(f)
    channel = guildInfo[ctx.message.guild.id]
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Welcome ""!",
                          description=f"We're so glad you're here !", color=discord.Color.green())
    await channel.send(embed=embed) ```
````

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the [member intent](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.members) to receive `on_member_join` events. You can do this while creating your bot object by adding an intent option:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents, other_options)
```

**Note**

If your bot is verified you require the `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` which you can request on the bot page of your application.

**Also:**

On this line here:
`embed = discord.Embed(title="Welcome ""!",` it will error out as there are quotes in a quoted string, if you want to keep those quotes switch the quotes to single quotes (')

Comment: Hello
Thank you for your reply so I added to my prefix `intents=intents` and now it looks like this 
`client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, intents=intents,)`

but when I try to join the channel with my test account I get an error 
`line 205, in on_member_join
    channel = guildInfo[ctx.message.guild.id]
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'message'`

witch is  ` channel = guildInfo[ctx.message.guild.id] ` from the welcome code

Comment: @TK12481 this is because the parameter passed in the `on_member_join` is a member object as showed [in the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_member_join). So to get the guild id, it would be `ctx.guild.id`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help everything is working now :)

Comment: Good to know, good luck for the rest of your project :)